# .appxbundle is generating instead of .appxupload - uwp

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, package, windows-10

I want to publish my app on Microsoft store. Found that we should generate ".appxupload" package for achieving it. I have followed this official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) to generate .appxupload file. But it always generating appxbundle. What is the reason for it? How can I create an appxupload file then?

1. I have selected Yes in the first dialog asking if you want to build packages to upload to Dev Center.
2. Selected the app name for  package (or reserved a new one  with the Windows Dev Center portal).
3. selected all three architecture configurations (x86, x64, and ARM) in the Select and Configure Packages dialog.

But finally I got an appxbundle file.

Comment: where are you searching for the appxupload file ? have you tried right clicking your project and opening the project in file explorer, there you should have `AppPackages` folder which will have your appxupload file. Note : Do not go into individual folders inside the `AppPackages` folder.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for it? How can I create an appxupload file then?

You could select `Never` in this checkbox if you don't want to generate an bundle file.

[image]

> Found that we should generate ".appxupload" package for achieving it.

That means that we should not upload the .appx file inside the folder, which is pre-complied and should be sideloaed on real device for testing purpose. We're supposed to upload the .appxupload file outside the folder. But it has nothing to do with bundle or non-bundle format.

[image]
[image]

For Store submission, you could upload `_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload` format package for your UWP app. 
One app bundle can contain your packages for all architectures. With an app bundle, a user will only download the relevant files, rather than all possible resources, which can be helpful if you've defined language-specific assets, a variety of image-scale assets, or resources that apply to specific versions of Microsoft DirectX.

For more details, you could refer to **[App bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements#app-bundles)**.

Answer (score 0):

appxupload is generated when .NET Native tool chain is checked by default in the release mode.